# Solve for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ without consider $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ of equation

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Solve for  $x\in  \mathbb{R}$

> $\frac{( \sqrt{x}+1)( \sqrt{x}+2)( \sqrt{x}+3)( \sqrt{x}+4)}{x+24\sqrt{x}+199} =\frac{x+40\sqrt{x}+271}{(\sqrt{x}+5)(\sqrt{x}+6)(\sqrt{x}+7)(\sqrt{x}+8)} $

I try to convert $\sqrt{x}+4.5 = y $, and the equation becomes

$ (y^{2}-0.5^{2})(y^{2}-1.5^{2})(y^{2}-2.5^{2})(y^{2}-3.5^{2})= \frac{1}{16}(4y^{2}+60y+445)(4y^{2}+124y+445)$

That doesn't make any sense for me to solve for $x \in  \mathbb{R}$ without bother complex roots.

How could we find out or rearrange the equation for solving only  $x \in  \mathbb{R}$.

Thank you any reply.

Comment: @Milten OK ,I've been edited.

Comment: Better try $\sqrt{x}+4$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The solution is given by $$x=(-4+\sqrt{17})^2$$

Comment: I know Friedrich Schiller, it is a famous poet.

Answer (score 1):

If $t=\sqrt{x}+4$ we get $$(t^2-1)(t^2-4)(t^2-9)(t^2+4t) = (t^2+32t-95)(t^2+16t-87)$$